# Oracle trigger- update record after update on same table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to make trigger in oracle database. when some one change the status its status again change to unpaid so that other user can use same number for payment.
I have write below code but it not change status.
Please help me in this regard. Thankyou.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PAY.TRG_UPDATE_NUMBER

AFTER UPDATE ON PAY.MYBILL

BEGIN

UPDATE PAY.MYBILL

SET STATUS='U'

WHERE MYNUMBER='123456789';

END;
```

Comment: `NUMBER` is a reserved keyword in Oracle, you should not use it as column name. And why do you provide a string for a numeric value?

Comment: Try `AFTER UPDATE ON PAY.MYBILL`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Prevent `PAY.MYBILL.STATUS` from changing? But if it must always be 'U', why do you store it at all? Or is it just the status for the one number you want to protect? Or what else?

Comment: What do you mean by "when some one change the status its status again change"? And what do you mean by "so that many user can use same number"?

Comment: yes just for single number I want that it status always remain unpaid i.e 'U'

Answer (score 2):

You want a trigger that ensures that the status for a particular number never changes and always remains 'U'.

For this to happen you need a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. Then, a trigger in Oracle is meant to manipulate the updating data directly, not via an update statement. And you need `FOR EACH ROW`, so you can react on a single row's update.

In an update tigger, the old values are accessable via `:old` and the new values via `:new`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pay.trg_update_number
BEFORE UPDATE OF status ON pay.mybill
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.mynumber = 123456789 THEN
    :new.status := 'U'; -- or :new.status := :old.status;
  END IF;
END trg_update_number;
```

Instead of `IF` / `THEN` you can also use a `WHEN` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pay.trg_update_number
BEFORE UPDATE OF status ON pay.mybill
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.mynumber = 123456789)
BEGIN
  :new.status := 'U'; -- or :new.status := :old.status;
END trg_update_number;
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Its really helpful

Comment: Is their is any method in trigger that due date daily change to current date?

Comment: A trigger reacts on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. It does not proactively read and manipulate all your table entries that are due.